# Execute multiple conditions when the cursor is clicked within div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My task: Initially, all three elements in the example are in the default value. When you click the mouse on the div (id="main") "first element" (or any other), I want the color of this div to change from green to red and the inscription "Active" to appear in this div. Next, when you click on the "second element" (or "third element") div, the value of the div with "first element" should become default, and the borders of the "second element" (or "third element") should turn red and the inscription "Active" should appear. However, when you press the "submenu" button, the above actions should not occur (that is, when you press this button, the borders should not turn red and the word "Active" should not appear).

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspicious-platform-vj5td9

```
    const data = [
  { id: "1", title: "first element" },
  { id: "2", title: "second element" },
  { id: "3", title: "third element" },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div id="main" className="App">
          <div id="text">{item.title}</div>
          <button>submenu</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I haven't explained something clearly, you can ask me any questions.

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve this? You are expected to make an attempt.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We're not a free coding service.

Comment: FYI, you're repeating ID values, which is invalid HTML (and about anywhere in life--IDs must be unique or they don't ID anything). It seems odd that you'd repeat a "main" element anyway.

Comment: I can't quite tell if this is a duplicate of, or simply related to, the previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77587445/82548

Answer (score -1):

I edit your code like below.

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/twilight-snowflake-wnvd2q)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { id: "1", title: "first element" },
  { id: "2", title: "second element" },
  { id: "3", title: "third element" },
];

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div id="main" className="App">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <div
            className={item.id === active ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => setActive(item.id)}
          >
            {item.id == active ? "active" : item.title}
          </div>
          <button>submenu</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Adrid Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, you did not quite understand my question. I meant to make a div active (that is, make the borders red and display the word “active”) by clicking on it (any place inside the div, except the submenu button). And when you click on the submenu button, nothing should happen

Comment: I just edited the code.

Comment: @Adrid Sorry, but the "submenu" button must be within the red border. That is, the red border should wrap the inscription “... element” or “active” (depending on the state), as well as the “submenu” button

Comment: @Paul, Put button in `div` element with `active` class. I think you don't try anything yourself to solve this problem.